# How do you test save() operations for Spring-Data JPA Repositories?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I've just started learning JPA and I'm using Spring-Data with Hibernate under the covers. I have everything working it seems, and I'd like to test the underlying database to make sure JPA/Hibernate is doing what I think it should. However, whenever I do a save() to an entity, Hibernate does not update the primary key (which is auto-generated) like basic Hibernate used to. The id is always 0, even though I know the insert statements were successfully generated and likely sent to the database.

How can I get Spring-Data/JPA to update the primary key of an entity when it's saved? I am using AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.

Comment: could you post your test source? have you tried to reassign the returned value? person = repo.save(person);?

Comment: @reagten actually, that worked. With Hibernate, you don't have a return value with the save operation, but I guess you have to with JPA. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the return value of the save() operation

```
person = repo.save(person);
```

Comment: What will be returned if save was unsuccess? I want to know how to check if save was success or not?

Comment: You can check it by using `if (person != null)` and return a response.

Comment: The documentation says entity will never be null.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-

Comment: In the case save failed for any reason, save will throw IllegalArgumentException so it will never be null.